# Is it possible to reverse the UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2

Is it possible to reverse the UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical so the first View will be pushed down and the second View is behind the first View.

Answer (score 2):

To my best knowledge there are no apis available for you to do this.

But if you have to achieve this, you can add the second view below the first view, then animate the first view by setting its frame.origin.y to (height of the view + its origin) and set the appropriate animation duration.